# Javascript not working inside bootstrap carousel item?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

I ran into this issue and wonder if there's a solution to it:

I have a HTML5 page with a bootstrap carousel on it, which contains some DIV's that show some content. One of these DIV's also contains some buttons that are meant to call some JS functions. I noticed that none of these functions ever get called, even a simple console.log does not work:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" >
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active" >
            <button onclick="console.log('TEST!');">TEST</button>
...
```

All tags are closed correctly, I just omitted further lines for clarity here. The carousel itself works as expected, nothing wrong with that, but the Javascript within it does not show any reaction. When I place the same button tag outside the carousel, the console gives me a "TEST!" in the console.

What's the problem here, can this be fixed? Or do I need to avoid the carousel when I need JS within my content?

Comment: Maybe carousel controls overlap your btns? Everything is working OK for me http://plnkr.co/edit/RISHZEsKntIm0oowcDYu (can you setup a simple example like this one?)